# Display XML content in Flash movie as Text

Tags: actionscript-3

Inside a Flash Movie (Actionscript 3) I need to display the content of a XML file.

I am passing the url of the file as a parameter. So I am using the following:

```
var file : XML;

var url = loaderInfo.parameters.url;

var loader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
loader.load(new URLRequest(url));

function onLoadComplete(e:Event){
  file = new XML(e.target.data);  
} // OnLoadComplete
```

How can I display the entire content of the XML file, as text, in the Flash Movie?

Probably the content will be big so I would like to have scroll bars.

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: The following link might be of some help
http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/loadxml/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this for example.

```
//... previous code
loader.load(new URLRequest(url));

var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField(); 
myTextBox.width = 200; 
myTextBox.height = 150; 
myTextBox.multiline = true; 
myTextBox.wordWrap = true; 
myTextBox.background = true; 
myTextBox.border = true; 
addChild(myTextBox);


function onLoadComplete(e:Event){
  file = new XML(e.target.data);
  myTextBox.text = file.toString(); 
}
```